# Ajax + php как отобразить результат в разных div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день!

Пишу корзину. Необходимо при изменении количества товаров сразу делать пересчеты и обновлять суммы в разных местах страницы.

Использую следующую схему:

```
function XmlHttp()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    try{xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
    catch(e)
    {
        try {xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} 
        catch (E) {xmlhttp = false;}
    }

    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function ajax(param)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) req = new XmlHttp(); 


    method=(!param.method ? "POST" : param.method.toUpperCase());


    if(method=="GET")
    {
        send=null;
        param.url=param.url+"&ajax = true";
    }
    else
    {
        send="";
        for (var i in param.data) 
            send += i + "=" + param.data[i] + "&";

        send = send + "ajax = true";
    }

    req.open(method, param.url, true);

    if(param.statbox) 
    {
        document.getElementById(param.statbox).innerHTML = '<img src="src/img/loading.gif" style="width:50px;">';
    }

    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //req.setRequestHeader('Cookie', document.cookie);
    req.send(send);


    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)   
        {
            if(param.success) {
                param.success(req.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
}


        ajax({
                url:"src/lib/index.php",
                statbox:box,
                method:"POST",
                //requestHeaders: [ 'Cookie', document.cookie ],
                dataType: "html", //Тип данных
                data: 
                {
                    TypeInput:  'Type1',
                    param1:     p1,
                    param2:     p2
                },
                success:function(data){document.getElementById(box).innerHTML=data;}
            });
```

Есть - statbox:box куда собственно возвращается результат, после выполнения скрипта.
Я хочу передавать скажем сразу 3 или 4 элемента, чтобы обновить информацию в них.

Кто поможет с этим? Спасибо!

Comment: Ну передавайте,что у вас не получается? `success:function(data){ вот в этой функции вы можете делать с полученными data что угодно }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не брать во внимание лишние проверки и сумбур, после получения ответа от сервера в ajax запросе, вы попадаете в метод success если всё хорошо.
Из этого следует, что в

```
$.ajax({
...,
success: function(response) {
  $(любойэлемент).html(response);
  $(любойэлемент).html(response);
  $(любойэлемент).html(response);
  $(любойэлемент).html(response);
}
});
```

можно указать любые селекторы.

Answer (score 0):

Если данные выводятся в одном виде, то можно написать какую-нибудь универсальную функцию:

```
fuction updateData(selectors, data) {
    for(var i in selectors) $(selectors[i]).html(data);
}
// Использовать так
updateData(['.basket','#small-basket'],newPrice);
```

Но это если данные отображаются одинаково, иначе для каждого блока свою функцию писать. А поместить, как говорят выше, в ф-цию `success`